# Making links to Places in this document work in vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to make a VBA script that will take all the headings in a document and make a table of contents out of them, with hyperlinks to each of the headings. The headings are all found, parsed and all the hyperlinks are made, however they don't correctly reach their destination which is a place within the document. The default 'create hyperlink to Place in this document' code looks like this:

```
Selection.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Range.Fields(1).Result.Select
Selection.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Delete
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:="", _
    SubAddress:="_Test_Heading"
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
```

This is the code that you would get if you recorded a macro while using the 'Edit hyperlink'  window.

[Edit hyperlink window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3SPY.png)

The address field where normally there would be a URL is empty, while the subaddress field is filled by the name of the header with underscores.

I think the problem is that Word defaults to 'Existing file or web page' rather than 'Place in this document', even if 'Place in this document' were specified prior. If I switch the mode of a link to 'Place in this document' without changing the subaddress or anything else, it works - but having to go and do that for each link defeats the purpose of the script. I've been looking all over for a way to express 'Place in this document' in VBA but haven't found anything. Tried bookmarks as an alternative and that didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Word? It does that for you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-table-of-contents-882e8564-0edb-435e-84b5-1d8552ccf0c0

Comment: Word has a very solid table of contents feature that does exactly this. Why are you not using that? You are reinventing the wheel. In Word, it is a TOC field.

Comment: @Charles Kenyon As stated in the original post, the goal was to use VBA. Word's built in functionality inserts a separate object, and doesn't link properly to its targets. But thank you for your input after ignoring my question and the solution I provided.

Comment: You can insert a TOC with vba as well.Again, you are reinventing the wheel. You are certainly free to do that. Thank you for sharing your ingenuity.

Comment: Again, I already know of Word's TOC function. It does not work the way I want it to, and it is also not extensible with other VBA macros that I am running, hence why I wanted it in VBA. You are welcome for the solution that I provided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a workaround using cross-referencing. In case it helps anyone in the future:

```
Private Function GetLevel(strItem As String) As Integer

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim longDiff As Integer

    strOriginal = RTrim$(strItem)
    strTemp = LTrim$(strOriginal)
    longDiff = Len(strOriginal) - Len(strTemp)
    GetLevel = (longDiff / 2) + 1
    
End Function

Sub TableofContents()

Dim i As Integer
Dim AllHeadings As Variant

AllHeadings = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine

For i = LBound(AllHeadings) To UBound(AllHeadings)
    strtext = Trim$(AllHeadings(i))
    Level = GetLevel(CStr(AllHeadings(i)))

    If Level = 2 Then            
        Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Heading", ReferenceKind:= _
        wdContentText, ReferenceItem:=i, InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
        IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
        Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If

Next

End sub
```

The first function gets the level of the heading.

The second part moves to the top of the document and starts inserting cross-references to the headings that I want (in this case I want it to be = 2).

Comment: @Timothy As stated in the original post, the goal was to use VBA. Word's built in functionality inserts a separate object, and doesn't link properly to its targets. But thank you for your input after ignoring my question and the solution I provided.

Comment: I suggest that you invest some time in gaining a better understanding of the built-in functionality. You will find applications are much easier to automate when you have a thorough understanding of how to use them, and you will spend less time coming up with creative fixes for things that aren't broken.

Comment: Again, I already know of Word's TOC function. It does not work the way I want it to, and it is also not extensible with other VBA macros that I am running, hence why I wanted it in VBA. You are welcome for the solution that I provided.

Comment: Again, your comment shows that you do not understand the TOC function as well as you think. A TOC field of { TOC \o "2-2" \h \n } does exactly what you want. You can learn about the various TOC switches [here](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCSwitches.htm)